# WPF CheckBox.IsChecked binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a datagrid with a variable number of columns that I am generating programatically. It contains DataGridTemplateColumns, each with a DockPanel containing a CheckBox and a TextBlock.

Binding code:

```
    Binding bindingPicked = new Binding(string.Format("Prices[{0}].Picked", i));
    bindingPicked.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
```

CheckBox code:

```
    FrameworkElementFactory factoryCheckBox = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
    factoryCheckBox.SetValue(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, bindingPicked);
```

Picked property:

```
    private bool _picked;
    public bool Picked
    {
        get { return _picked; }
        set { _picked = value; }
    }
```

When the datagrid is initialized, the Picked getters are called as expected. However, when I check/uncheck a checkbox, the setter isn't called. What is causing this? I do not want to use a DependencyProperty, and I don't think it should be needed as I just need the property setter to be called when the user clicks the CheckBox.

EDIT: Apparently I am a moron, I simply forgot
bindingPicked.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
Feel free to close this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bindingPicked.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
```

That should do it :)

Comment: Yeah... What a stupid mistake (and 2 hours wasted "fixing" it). Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

I Think you should Implement INotifyPropertyChanged's and call the event in set

Answer (score 0):

As above, you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged
The correct pattern to follow is:

```
private bool _picked;
public bool Picked
{
    get { return _picked; }
    set
    {
        if (_picked != value)
        {
            _picked = value;
            if (null != PropertyChanged)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Picked"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The UpdateSourceTrigger property tells databinding when to update the source.
For example, with a TextBox, the default is LostFocus. For most other controls it is PropertyChanged.